# 220 VAC Control Transformer "voltage on" indicator light.

Tags: light, indicator

[image]

I would like to know where to place an indicator light (what voltage, as well) for the incoming 220VAC, after the 2 pole circuit breaker? The IEC Connector will provide 220VAC to the transformer, 120VAC to each leg, then the transformer will supply 120VAC to our equipment. The 120VAC "Power On" indicator light is wired below the transformer.  I am just having some issues with the 220 wiring.  Would a 220 VAC Panel Light illuminate, when wired across the two hot wires? (H1 and H4)  Where would a neutral come from, if it at all needed?

Comment: Your primary wiring looks wrong for 220VAC in.

Comment: Post a link showing technical details on the transformer. It could be 120/240 or 240/480 are the more common I have seen. If the transformer primary is the lower voltage rating  120/240 connect H1 to H3 and H2 to H4. If if it is the higher rating connect 220/440 Connect connect H1 to H2 and H3 to H4.   You are connecting the primary windings in series or parallel depending on voltage. The identification is such as the windings phase properly. I have  secondarie connect the same. The 120V light as shown would be in my opinion the best solution as it actually tells you if power is at the plugs.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know where to place an indicator light (what voltage, as well)

The voltage required is the voltage at that point in the circuit.

> ... for the incoming 220VAC, after the 2 pole circuit breaker?

A good choice but if it doesn't light you'll need to check the breaker to see if that's the cause. You could add lights both sides of the breaker.

> The IEC Connector will provide 220VAC to the transformer, 120VAC to each leg, then the transformer will supply 120VAC to our equipment.

Not the way it's wired in the schematic. Both 120 V windings are in parallel and will have 220 VAC applied to them resulting in smoke.

Remove H1-H3 and H2-H4 links and rewire with H2-H3 link.

> The 120VAC "Power On" indicator light is wired below the transformer. I am just having some issues with the 220 wiring.

I reckon that that's all you really need. Transformer failure is relatively unlikely given the proper circuit breaker.

> Would a 220 VAC Panel Light illuminate, when wired across the two hot wires? (H1 and H4)

Yes.

> Where would a neutral come from, if it at all needed?

The bulb knows nothing about neutral. It only knows about the voltage difference between the ends of the filament. If there is 220 V between the supply terminals then there will be 220 V across the lamp.

Answer (score 0):

To your question on the bulb wiring, it's correct that the term "neutral" is irrelevant in this case. A 220-240V lamp will illuminate when the voltage is 220-240V between the terminals, so you would show it in exactly the same way that you show the other one on the 120V side; connected between the two voltage lines. **You WOULD need to use a 240V rated bulb however**. I suppose you are doing this so that you can determine if the primary or secondary breaker has tripped? Because other than that, it's a little redundant in that if the secondary light is On you can assume that the primary is as well. If it is Off, you know it's not working and you are going to look at it anyway so you will be able to see if the primary breaker is tripped or not. The only thing this 2nd light adds is to tell you that the primary breaker tripped without actually looking at it. In 30+ years, I have never once seen a small transformer primary fail, so I personally wouldn't bother, but it's your money...

But I don't know why some people are telling you that the primary of your transformer is shown wrong, that is the connection I see for most 240/480 V primary transformers. Maybe it's because you didn't specify that detail, but its the most common type of Control Power Transformer, in North America anyway.

[image]

Comment: "*But I don't know why some people are telling you that the primary of your transformer is shown wrong ...*". A couple of things: it's fed from an IEC socket which won't be rated for 480 V. I expected it to be a 120 - 120 V transformer. OP didn't specify location so the question is a bit vague.